# PouchDB slowdown due to store count on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, indexeddb, pouchdb

I'm currently writing a hybrid application that uses IndexedDB + PouchDB to cache several pieces of information from a REST endpoint. Each endpoint is saved to a PouchDB store, so stores like '/location','/users','/products', etc. I've noticed that when I start opening more `new PouchDB(name)`s my application started to slow down on my iOS device running iOS 13. On my android 10 device, the performance of my application much better though still not great.

On the initial launch of the application, several fetch requests are fired to store the required REST endpoint's response into different PouchDB stores (roughly around 60 or so stores).

When navigating through the application, there are items you can tap on to get more information regarding that item. The additional information is stored within PouchDB and so a `pouchDB.find()` is used to retrieve the data from that store.

```html
+-----------+------------+------------+
|  device   |   Launch   | navigation |
+-----------+------------+------------+
| ios13     | 13minutes  | 3.5seconds |
| android10 | 91seconds  | 0.6seconds |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

From a performance tests of my application, iOS seems to be taking a significantly longer time to complete the same tasks. since things like navigation should be pulling from the cached values in PouchDB instead of the REST endpoint.

I wondering if anyone one else has experience this type of slow down caused by having several PouchDB stores? If so, did you have any work arounds or solutions to the fixing the performance issues with several stores on iOS?

Comment: That's a LOT of concurrent pouchdb instances!  What are the maximum number of concurrent requests allowed in the webview? Once everything is fetched does performance increase? Have you tried serializing the open and fetch for each db?

Comment: maybe im just using pouchdb incorrectly, what would you think is your average number of instances within your experience? To answer your questions: 1) i'm unsure what you mean. Anytime i navigate and look around im sending anywhere between 4 to 8 concurrent requests to different stores. 2) after everything is fetch and im only pulling from pouchdb im getting the 3.5s performance. 3) not sure what you mean by serialize and open.

Comment: When you say "store" do you mean `store = new PouchDB(name)`? So 60 different db's open at same time?  I've only ever gone with single user db's, pouchdb <--> couchdb. Your 'fetch' - is it sync? By serialize I mean perform HTTP operations one after the other, not concurrently.  How much data are we talking about? If you have indexes (e.g. views) then those build on first read.  You might want to post this question on [https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues).  Here we need  a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes, thats correct. 60 `new PouchDB(name)` are created at launch if they don't exist already. The fetch requests are occurring async. most of the stores have indexes. And the navigation speeds is based on successive reads, not the initial read. initially (iOS13.3.1), I made a test where I made a forloop with `store = new PouchDB(name)` and created 100 stores and only inserted 1 row into 1 store (99 empty stores). then doing a `db.find()` resulted in almost 100ms response time. But since the release of iOS13.4 i haven't been able to reproduce the same time. its always sub 1ms.